# How can I bind a driver with a USB device?

Tags: linux, usb, driver, bind, device

I am writing a USB device drive for linux. it's for a joystick.
every time plug it in, linux loads a hid driver. is there a way to tell Linux to load mine when I plug it in? or at least not load the default one?

I can echo the id in unbind of the default driver and echo it in bind of my driver; but I would like something more automatic..
thanks

Comment: What does "linux lad a hid driver" mean?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos:  I think he meant to write "Linux loads an HID driver."  HID = Human Interface Device.

Comment: If you have full access to the kernel source tree, you can add the driver to the `hid_have_special_driver` array in `drivers/hid/hid-core.c`. That will cause `hid-generic` to ignore the device. But I very much hope that there is a solution which can work without modifying existing modules, and which would therefore be suitable for extra modules added via DKMS or similar. Unfortunately there appears to be no `usbhid` quirk for this use case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Own USB driver taking precedence over usbhid

If you want to prevent binding to the `usbhid` driver, you can use its `HID_QUIRK_IGNORE` (= 4) setting. To stick with the example Karl Bielefeldt used, add

```
options usbhid quirks=0x15c2:0x0043:0x04
```

to some `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` file (and perhaps recreate your initramfs). That will tell `hid-core` to ignore that device. So `usbhid` will have a look at it but leave it for some other driver instead.

## Own HID driver taking precedence over hid-generic

However, if your other driver is a HID driver not an USB driver, then you *need* `usbhid` to bind to the driver on the USB level, and you need your own HID driver to take precedence over `hid-generic`. This is the problem I'm facing my self, and for which I haven't found a solution yet, short of unbinding and rebinding the device later on.

Comment: This hid-generic rebinding is such a hassle. I wonder how nobody found a better solution. And there is SO LITTLE information in the Internet, that I wonder if anyone actually writes drivers for Linux in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

[Here's](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8512485&postcount=64) a thread with a fix for a similar problem.  To summarize, you add something like the following to one of your `/etc/udev/rules.d` files:

```
SYSFS{idVendor}=="15c2", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0043", MODE="0666", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n $id:1.0 >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind;\
echo -n $id:1.1 >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind'"
```

Comment: The syntax for udev rules seems to have changed. This would now be:
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb" ATTR{idVendor}=="15c2", ATTR{idProduct}=="0043", MODE="0666", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n $id:1.0 >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind; echo -n $id:1.1 >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind'"`. Note that this also work with other drivers, like `uvcvideo`, not just `usbhid`.

Answer (score 1):

http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/ is very similar to the above answer, maybe some more details.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. The answer itself should contain the essential useful information. Links are good as references.